# Server Thread-method getInstance() not found

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server

Im trying to run a Server using the following code.But when i try to create a Thread i get  `method getInstance()` is not found error.Please help.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Server {
   public static void main(String args[]) {       
     Thread discoveryThread = new Thread(DiscoveryThread.getInstance());    
     discoveryThread.start();
   }   
}

class DiscoveryThread implements Runnable {
  DatagramSocket socket;    

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      //Keep a socket open to listen to all the UDP trafic that is destined for this port
      socket = new DatagramSocket(8888, InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"));
      socket.setBroadcast(true);

      while (true) {
        System.out.println(getClass().getName() + ">>>Ready to receive broadcast packets!");

        //Receive a packet
        byte[] recvBuf = new byte[15000];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(recvBuf, recvBuf.length);
        socket.receive(packet);

        //Packet received
        System.out.println(getClass().getName() + ">>>Discovery packet received from: " + packet.getAddress().getHostAddress());
        System.out.println(getClass().getName() + ">>>Packet received; data: " + new String(packet.getData()));

        //See if the packet holds the right command (message)
        String message = new String(packet.getData()).trim();
        if (message.equals("DISCOVER_FUIFSERVER_REQUEST")) {
          byte[] sendData = "DISCOVER_FUIFSERVER_RESPONSE".getBytes();

          //Send a response
          DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, packet.getAddress(), packet.getPort());
          socket.send(sendPacket);

          System.out.println(getClass().getName() + ">>>Sent packet to: " + sendPacket.getAddress().getHostAddress());
        }
      }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(DiscoveryThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }
  }
```

Error:

```
Server.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
Thread discoveryThread = new Thread(DiscoveryThread.getInstance());
                                                        ^
  symbol:   method getInstance()
  location: class DiscoveryThread
```

Comment: Why not `new DiscoveryThread` ?

Comment: Why are you surprised that a method you haven't written or inherited doesn't exist?

Comment: The `DiscoveryThread` class appears not to have a `getInstance()` method.  Try constructing it using `new` instead.

Comment: @WarrenDew Thanks..

Comment: @techno Since it helped, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DiscoveryThread` class appears not to have a `getInstance()` method.  Try constructing it using `new` instead.